# Code hangswhile running

Tags: c++

The code hangs while executing. Please help me to understand what is the problem here
It stcks after the first travers and does not even enters the reverse function. Could not understand the issue:
 Help me on it.

```
# include<iostream>
# include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct sLL
{
   int data;
   sLL * next;
};

void createList(sLL ** head, int n)
{
   if(n == 0)
   {
      return;
   }
   sLL * temp = (sLL *) malloc(sizeof(sLL));
   if(temp != NULL)
   {
      temp->data = rand() % 100;
      temp->next = NULL;
      *head = temp;
      //head = &(temp->next);
      createList(&(temp->next), n - 1);
   }
}

void traverse(sLL * head)
{
   cout<<"In traverse"<<endl;
   while(head) {
      cout<<head->data<<"->";
      head=head->next;
   }
   cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
   cout.flush();
   return;
} 

 sLL* reverse(sLL * head)
 {
    sLL * temp = NULL, * newNode = NULL;
    while(head) {   
       newNode = head->next; // to traverse forword
       head->next = temp;
       temp = head; // Current node value which we use in next itr as a previous node value.
       newNode = head; // assigning newNode vlaue back to head so that we can traverse forward.
    }
    return temp; // final node value will be in temp i.e the current node value.
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    sLL * head = NULL, *temp = NULL;
    cout<<"Enter the number of nodes :";
    cin>>n;
    createList(&head, n);
    cout<<"\nCreate Done"<<endl;
    traverse(head);
    cout.flush();
    cout<<"Reverse Start";
    temp = reverse(head);
    cout<<"reverse done";
    traverse(temp);
}
```

Comment: Do the values get printed?

Comment: Narrow down the problem by selectively commenting things out until very few lines remain. That's call _debugging_ and will probably solve your problem for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't reassign the head value at all

```
while(head)
    //loop
```

Here, the head pointer is never altered. So the loop is an infinite one.

Comment: can you please point out the place.

Comment: @saurabh In the while loop at the `traverse()` function

Comment: Sir head=head->next; is present there...

Comment: @saurabh sorry the reverse function

Comment: Its not an Infinite loop..... with in the while i am travesing the  also travese goes fine in outout

Comment: @saurabh It is an infinite loop (in the `reverse` function), because `while (head)` is always true.

Comment: cool Sir.. it worked... But I am not able to understand why its impact was so huge?.. At the first instance I was not even able to see prints which I put in the create function... Could you please throw some light on it..?

Comment: @saurabh: Accept the answer if it had helped you

Comment: The while loop has become an infinite loop, as the head value never becomes NULL, and the condition for the while loop is always true

Answer (score 0):

Your comment contradicts the code here:

```
newNode = head; // assigning newNode vlaue back to head so that we can traverse forward.
```

If you do what the comment says it should work better:

```
head = newNode; // assigning newNode value back to head so that we can traverse forward.
```

Comment: got it thanks aswin already figured out